# Dynamic fields data save to web services in android

Tags: android, custom-fields

I am getting multiple fields dynamically from JSON data. To save data of dynamic fields into web services i prefer to call by id. But i unable to get the id of that fields. So I need to know how to get ids of dynamic fields.

Here is my JSON response:

```
{
"sections": [
   {
       "head": "Section A",
       "sort": 1,
       "section_id": 3,
       "cols": "2",
       "fields": [
           {
               "id": 5,
               "template_id": 2,
               "section_id": 3,
               "label": "A1",
               "itype": "1",
               "idefault": "",
               "ioptions": "",
               "required": "N",
               "ivalids": "0",
               "sort": 1,
               "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
               "updated_at": "2018-09-23 05:32:59",
               "deleted_at": null
           },
           {
               "id": 6,
               "template_id": 2,
               "section_id": 3,
               "label": "A2",
               "itype": "1",
               "idefault": "",
               "ioptions": "",
               "required": "N",
               "ivalids": "0",
               "sort": 1,
               "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
               "updated_at": "2018-09-23 05:32:59",
               "deleted_at": null
           }
       ]
   }
 ]
 }
```

> If "itype"=1 dynamic_field = edittext,   "itype"=2 dynamic_field =
>   spinner and so on.

In my response, I am getting "itype"=1 so i am dynamically displaying two edit texts.

And "label" from JSON used as id for a dynamic field. If I integrate API, it's getting the error as "can't resolve the id".
I don't know how to resolve this error.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1I7l.png)

Comment: Your issue is when you parse the JSON, r8?

Comment: I already parse JSON data and get the dynamic fields.But after button click i want to save data in POST method.Then i unable to get the ids of dynamic fields.
My issue is How to access id of dynamic fields.

Comment: Try to parse JSON according to your needs on the server side and If You need some more relevant information from that JSON then add that information into the JSON then parse it on the server side.

Comment: I need to save the dynamic fields data into database.If i enter data on dynamic fields What to do to get that data(to save in database).?